How to save sessionID and use it in socket, using express and express-session
Im trying to make a site where multiple users are able to draw at the same time, but one of my challenges is trying to store cookies and session Ids. So basically, when a user connects, theyre given an id, upon refresh that id shoud be the same, and upon window close i want it to be the same.
This is what i have so far; it may look incomplete/messy because im in the middle of working on it:
const express = require("express");
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const { sessionMiddleware, wrap } = require('../server/sessionStore');

const { createServer } = require("node:http");
const { join } = require("node:path");

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  }
});

const db = require("../database/db");

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/canvas", (req, res) => {
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.visited
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.session.id +' connected');
  } else {
    res.send("Invalid session");
  }
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "../public/index.html"));
});

const clients = {};

io.use(wrap(sessionMiddleware));
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const sessionId = socket.request.session.id;

  clients[sessionId] = '#000000';

  db.getAllDrawingData((drawingData) => {
    socket.emit("loadDrawingData", drawingData);
  });

  // start drawing event
  socket.on('startDrawing', ({ x, y }) => {
    const data = { type: 'start', x, y, color: clients[sessionId] };
    db.insertDrawingData(sessionId, data); socket.broadcast.emit('startDrawing', { x, y, color: clients[sessionId] });
  });

  // drawing event
  socket.on('draw', ({ x, y }) => {
    const data = { type: 'draw', x, y, color: clients[sessionId] };
    db.insertDrawingData(sessionId, data); socket.broadcast.emit('draw', { x, y, color: clients[sessionId] });
  });

  // stop drawing event
  socket.on('stopDrawing', () => {
    const data = { type: 'stop' };
    db.insertDrawingData(sessionId, data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('stopDrawing');
  });

  // change stroke color event
  socket.on('changeStrokeColor', (color) => {
    clients[sessionId] = color;
    socket.broadcast.emit('changeStrokeColor', { socketId: sessionId, color });
  });

  socket.on('eraseDrawings', () => {
    db.eraseDrawings(sessionId);
    socket.broadcast.emit('eraseDrawings');
  });

  // disconnect event
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected');
    delete clients[sessionId];
  });
});

// Handle server shutdown gracefully
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT signal, shutting down...');
  db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error closing SQLite database:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('SQLite database connection closed successfully.');
    }
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGTERM signal, shutting down...');
  db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error closing SQLite database:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('SQLite database connection closed successfully.');
    }
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000");
});


//EDIT
const session = require("express-session");
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const config = require("./config");

const redisClient = new Redis({
  host: config.redis.host,
  port: config.redis.port,
});
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Could not establish a connection to Redis" + err);
});
redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("Connected to Redis");
});

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: "secret",
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sameSite: true,
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
  },
  genid: (req) => uuidv4() + "-" + Date.now(),
});

const wrap = (expressMiddleware) => (socket, next) =>
  expressMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);

module.exports = { sessionMiddleware, wrap };

As well, the code in the app.get("/") function doesnt work unless i change the endpoint, for example: "/canvas". MY code worked well without sessions, and just using socket.id data.
I tried inputting the app.get code into the io.on("connect"), and it worked, but it gave me a new id upon refresh. Ive gone through so many resources and they all have their session code in their app.get functions, and theyre all referring to login/signup which im not doing, i just want if the same user connects that it uses the same sessionID, but for me its just not working, im stumped.

Regarding the code under 'app.get("/")' that is not working for you, what is the path of "index.html"? Is it under the public directory?

Could you share the code inside './sessionStore'? I want to see if there is something wrong..

@RimonFedyuk Yes, my index.html is under a public folder, when i have my 'app.get("/")' without an endpoint, i m able to 'res.sendFile(join(__dirname, index.html"));' but if i change my endpoint to let's say 'app.get("/canvas")' then i have to change to 'res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "public/index.html"));'.
could you briefly explain why if thats part of the issue.
I alos provided the sessionStore file for you in my post and updated my server.js code.
Thank you for your help
